# Как запретить CUPS добавлять принтеры автоматически?

Tags: linux, cups

CUPS находит в локальной сети принтер, ставит его, но не правильно определяет драйвер или подключение (implicitclass://sklad2_sklad2/) - в итоге куча неработающих принтеров в списке.

Comment: Странно, у меня CUPS никогда не ставил принтеры автоматически

Comment: Похоже в cups-browserd.conf надо повыключать всё.

Comment: И заодно грохнуть udev правила все)